# If I make a YouTube video private within the YouTube website, will an embedded version of that video still be visible in a Mobile App?

Tags: youtube, video, mobile, embed

**The situation:**
We want to upload a video to YouTube in order to embed it into a Mobile App.

**The problem:**
We previously uploaded a similar video to our channel which we don't want to delete. For this reason, we would like to upload the new video, embed it in the Mobile App and then make it private so that it can't be viewed within YouTube.

**The question:**
Once made private in YouTube, will the new video still be visible in the Mobile App?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed private videos, but private videos can only be shared with up to 50 people and you need to be logged into a Google account to view them.

What you are looking for is to make your video "Unlisted" which will mean other YouTube users won't find it in YouTube search results, via your user page or similar videos. This is what you want to be using if you want to share it on your app but keep it out of YouTube's public eye.
Please look at this page for more details of each option: 
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177

Comment: @MoscowMuleMonster If this solution worked, it would be great if you accepted the answer so as to let other people know that this solution was useful to you.